# Assistance Needed with Nesting IF, MIN, and CountIF (possibly?)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a golf scorecard tracker for match play. I am trying to make it so that there are 4 scores inputted. (2 from each team).. Common sense of the formula needed is: If one of the 2 scores from team A are the lowest, +1 for Team A. If team A has the lowest score, but also someone from Team B has that same low score, 0. If Team A does not have the MIN score, -1.

This is what I had so far that seemed to work, but my problem is that In the part where i Have

```
IF(OR(I8=I12,I8=I13,I9=I12,I9=I13),0,1)
```

it returns a 0 if 2 scores are the same but not the lowest.

Any help here is greatly appreciated. Here is the full formula I have thus far that is currently not working:

```
=IF(OR(I8=MIN(I8:I9,I12:I13),I9=MIN(I8:I9,I12:I13)),IF(OR(I8=I12,I8=I13,I9=I12,I9=I13),0,1),-1)
```

| ROW | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Data Set: |  |
| 8 | Team A | 4 |
| 9 | Team A | 5 |
| 10 | Match Score | *Formula Here* |
| 11 |  |  |
| 12 | Team B | 5 |
| 13 | Team B | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this that compares the MIN score of each team and returns the correct value:

```
=IF(MIN(I8:I9)=MIN(I12:I13),0,IF(MIN(I8:I9)<MIN(I12:I13),1,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! Rather than start another thread, would you be able to give a simple answer where: If MIN value occurs more than once, then "N/A", if only occurs once, "output player name who shot the MIN score"?